# MVC Options Select action link not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

When clicked, I want to go these links, but it doesn't work.
How can I make it work? Thanks.

```html
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <label class="control-label" for="Level">Filter</label>
   <select id="EType" class="form-control" name="EType">
       <option value="@Url.Action("Approver","Degree", new { Area = "Options", value=3 } )">ID</option> 
       <option value="@Url.Action("Approver","Degree", new { Area = "Options", value=4 } )">ID2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: "it doesent work" is not very specific.

Comment: when i click these options, nothing happens. Not going to the desired pages.

Comment: You'll need to implement `onchange` event via `js/jQuery` to achieve this. A selection from the select dropdown won't just redirect you to another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example. This is not MVC framework problem. Probably you used asp.net web form. This framework not working web form. You must use javascript methods. I create an example fastly for you with jQuery.

```js
// find elements
var selectItem = $("#EType")

// handle select and go to link
selectItem.on('change', function(){
  location.href = $(this).val();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <label class="control-label" for="Level">Filter</label>
   <select id="EType" class="form-control" name="EType">
     <option value="#">Select and go</option> 
     <option value="https://omer.mollamehmetoglu.com">ID</option> 
     <option value="https://www.onedio.com">ID2</option>     
     <option value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">ID3</option>   
   </select>
</div>
```